# How can I make a vector with all values of a column in R?

Tags: r, vector

I want to make a vector for a loop with al values of a column.
Is this possible?

Currently I did it like this:
Client_id_conversion_vector <- as.vector(Test$dimension1)

dimension1 are the clientId's I want in my vector

The problem is that I get the same value over and over

Comment: `Test$dimension1` should be a `vector`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including sample input and expected output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `unique` function:

```
Client_id_conversion_vector <- unique(Test$dimension1)
```